# Why wont this batch file work?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was trying to create a simple program that would show up your name after you entered it.

After spending a few hours trying to get this batch file to work on a windows 10 and windows 7 computers, I can't still figure out what is the problem. After you input your answer whether or not you confirm that that is your name, it is still not working.

I've tried to debug by putting `pause` just about everywhere and it continues not to work.

Can somebody please point out what is wrong? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
ECHO OFF 
setlocal

COLOR A
cls
:getName
ECHO test
echo Please input name.
set "name="
SET /P NAME=
if not defined NAME goto getName
ECHO %NAME%, is this correct? Y/N
set /p 097=
if %O97%==Y goto :begin
set favvid=0
set hack=0
:b
echo Input name
set name=
set /P name=
echo %name%, correct? Y/N
set 897=
set /p 897=
if %897%==N goto :c
if %897%==Y goto :begin
:c
echo Input name
set name=
set /P name=
echo %name%, correct? Y/N
set 897=
set /p 897=
if %897%==N goto b
if %897%==Y goto begin
echo Name = %NAME% Is now your name. Too many attempts
:begin
echo Hello %Name%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Avoid starting variable names with a number](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), this will avoid the
>   variable being [misinterpreted as a parameter](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

`%123_myvar%` in a batch script is parsed and then executed as `%1 23_myvar`

For proof, force `echo ON`.

And use (note that variable first character **is not** *cipher zero* but *letter* `O`.

```
set /p "O97=%name%, correct? Y/N "
if "%O97%"=="Y" goto :begin
rem note quoting in above commands
```

Consider using the [`CHOICE` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) as an alternative to `SET /P` (but accepts only one character/keypress).

Answer (score 1):

Two errors on the `if` lines:

1. You should not use numbers to start variables in a batch file as they are interpreted as the arguments passed to the batch file. `%0` is the batch file itself. `%1` is the first, `%8` is the 8th argument etc. (You can try `echo --%0--%1--%097%--` in the batch file to see what result it gives you.)

   Instead of this `if "%097%"=="Y" goto begin`

   Use this `if "%Answer%"=="Y" goto begin`

> Now also note that while your line `set /p 097=` has `097` when you
>   test for it in the next line with `%O97%` you do not have a `0` but
>   you have the letter `O`. This makes your test fail every time.

2. You need to put the string in quotes, like so:

   `if "%Answer%"=="Y" goto begin`
3. Finally note that the test is case sensitive. So when the user presses **y** it will be interpreted as the wrong answer. You need to add a `/I` to your test:

   `if`*`/I`*`"%Answer%"=="Y" goto begin`

One more point. After the `goto` you put colon some places, some places not, it is facultative but it is neater to keep it consistent.

Comment: `goto begin` and `goto :begin` are the same, a colon is facultative. I use colon consistently; it helps finding labels and corresponding GOTOs for instance…

Comment: thanks for catching it. oversight (I changed along with the other errors, so I thought both were affecting the result). I corrected this.